# Difference between these two wildcards

Tags: java, generics

Are the following method declarations,

```
public void testMethod(ArrayList<T extends Animal> list)
```

and

```
public <T extends Animal> void testMethod(ArrayList<T> list)
```

the same?

Comment: I think so, yes. The latter comes in handy when you need to enforce the same generic type on multiple arguments, or return something of the same generic type.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens: I think that's an answer.

Comment: I don't understand. Please could you be more clear? I am kind of new to generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the former does not compile, while the latter does.  Is it what you were asking?

If you meant difference between:

```
public void testMethod (ArrayList <? extends Animal> list)
```

and

```
public <T extends Animal> void testMethod (ArrayList <T> list)
```

then the difference is that in first case you cannot refer to actual type of `ArrayList` elements, while in second case you can.

Probably, the difference will be more obvious if we will consider the following two cases:

```
public void testMethod (
    ArrayList <? extends Animal> l1, 
    ArrayList <? extends Animal> l2)
```

and

```
public <T extends Animal> void testMethod (
    ArrayList <T> l1, ArrayList <T> l2)
```

In the first case, first argument is an `ArrayList` of some type that extends `Animal`, the second argument is an `Arraylist` or some (probably other) type that extends `Animal`.

In the second case, both arguments are `ArralList`s of **the same** type that extends `Animal`.

Comment: Oh yes. I meant this. But I am not able to grasp the answer

Comment: @user1801716 In the first example you don't have a "type variable" which is bound to the list's type parameter, so you can't do anything involving that type. In the second example you have: it's `T`.

Comment: "the former does not compile" it does if it is in the scope of a type `T` (e.g. a type parameter of the class)

Comment: Added more details that probably will make difference more clear.

Answer (score 4):

They ***aren't*** the same in one important way. For the first case, the generic parameter will be bound to the scope of the class, and will not change over multiple invocations of the method.

In the second case, the generic parameter will depend on the arguments the method is called with, and can be different for each separate invocation.

So, given this class:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Animal> {
    public void handleList1(List<T> list) {
       // implementation
    }

    public <U extends Animal> void handleList2(List<U> list) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Instantiating it as:

```
MyClass<Bear> test = new MyClass<Bear>();
```

You will only be able to call `handleList1` with lists of type `Bear`. On the other hand, you can call `handleList2` as:

```
test.handleList2(new ArrayList<Tiger>);
test.handleList2(new ArrayList<Lion>);
test.handleList2(new ArrayList<Puma>);
```

Because the generic parameter for it is determined by the argument supplied too the method.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Sure - added example, I'll format when I'm not typing on a phone

Comment: @Perception, i think you are answering different question, he is interested to see the difference between `List<? extends Animal>` as a parameter to function vs declaring the T type before the void.

Comment: @Michael - I don't think so. You might want to re-read the question.